# An error occurred checking the current user: error: Not Found

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

I just added a video to one of my site pages by editing page -> insert -> Video and Audio -> From Computer. The video is on the page now and works, but every time I load the page this message pops up.
[image]

I click OK and everything is fine. Not sure if this could have screwed anything up, but when I added this video, there was another one on the page. I didn't even need to delete the old one. This new one loaded in just fine, but it automatically deleted the older one from the page.

Comment: Is there any custom web part in this page? If it is possible, then delete the page and add video again ....... lol!

Comment: I have spotlight announcements and promoted links. Those are the only other two apps on the page besides the video I just added. This is weird. It's never done this before. I've had this site page up and running for a few weeks.

Comment: spotlight announcements is custom web part? if so, may be it is causing the error. Add this in other page and check if error exist

Comment: I've already deleted it from the page to see if the error message still occurs. It doesn't change anything. I will try this though.

Comment: check your spotlight announcements web part

Comment: I just added another page and inserted spotlight announcements in it. There is no error message. I hope I don't have to delete it from my site contents entirely.

Comment: It must be something related to the spotlight announcements. That app doesn't display until I click OK on the error message.

Comment: error message seems like it is from a custom web part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28794/discussion-between-atish-dipongkor-and-andrew).

Comment: I'm confused why it just started happening now though? This app has been on my page for weeks.

Comment: May be you did not consider some situation last time. you can debug it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this error is from another custom web part in the same page. It is not related to Video and Audio web part. check your custom web part and fix

Comment: Promoted Links is a custom web part I have on the page. I downloaded it from the store. Once again, I have no idea why this would become a problem multiple weeks after being added.

Answer (score 0):

A custom app downloaded from the sharepoint store was the problem.